# Cannot disable automatic update checks on Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: updates, kubuntu, 18.04

I am trying to disable automatic update checks on Kubuntu 18.04. I have unticked the option to check for updates daily by using *Settings -> Configure Software Sources -> Updates* in `muon` but the system keeps checking for updates on every startup.

The contents of */etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic* are

```
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "0";
APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "0";
APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "0";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "0";
```

Is there anything else that has to be done in order to stop those automatic checks completely?

Comment: How often you do start up? Is it more than once a day?

Comment: No, unless the system needs to reboot after an update or an installation. Do you mean that the update checks the system does during startup, do not depend on the setting I have unticked?

Comment: I don't have `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic`. 
 Could you run `sudo -H software-properties-kde` to get a window titled `Software Sources` . It has an `Updates` tab. Maybe try turning things off there?

Comment: That's exactly what the `muon` setting I described above does. It runs `software-properties-kde`.

Comment: Then I don't understand why I don't have `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic`. Did you create that file yourself?

Comment: No. It's there by default on both my systems. I installed 18.04 from scratch on both.

Comment: Mine is a clean install. Not an upgrade. Let's hope someone comes along to help you!

Answer (score 5):

To [disable automatic upgrades](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticSecurityUpdates) in Kubuntu 18.04, run:

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure --priority=low unattended-upgrades
```

and when prompted *Automatically download and install stable updates?*, choose "No" and follow the remaining prompts. To see the status of automatic upgrades, run:

```
$ apt-config dump APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade
```

The value produced (an integer) means how often to update automatically, in days. A zero value means disabled.

Answer (score 4):

At my 18.04.1 installation there was no file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic`.

After a short search I found:

```
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades
```

There I could disable my auto-updates. Maybe you could also have a look there for your solution.

I just zero-ed the values; so my content of `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades` is now:

```
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "0";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "0";
APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "0";
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing those values in periodic only seem to disable the automatic update of package lists.

To disable the annoying update-manager popup (also called update-notifier), I changed the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99update-notifier` from this:

```
DPkg::Post-Invoke {"if [ -d /var/lib/update-notifier ]; then touch /var/lib/update-notifier/dpkg-run-stamp; fi; /usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-updates-available 2>/dev/null || true";};
APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success {"/usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-updates-available 2>/dev/null || true";};
```

to this content:

```
//DPkg::Post-Invoke {"if [ -d /var/lib/update-notifier ]; then touch /var/lib/update-notifier/dpkg-run-stamp; fi; /usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-updates-available 2>/dev/null || true";};
//APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success {"/usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-updates-available 2>/dev/null || true";};
```

Finally, no more annoying notifications aka. popups.